# Clearing previously entered text in EditText field

Tags: android, android-edittext

Hey,
I'm trying to get my editText window to clear its contents when either:
1) It is reselected to enter different data or
2) A button is pressed to input predetermined data

This is not hint text. At the moment once the predetermined data is input it stays there and I can't clear it, even using delete.
I have tried putting editBox.setText("") in the onClick Listener and the addTextChangedListener (both before and on methods) using a boolean to determine if code has already been input, but it just ignores it.

```
foodBox.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            addFood();
            valueAdded=true;
        }           
    });


    dogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (valueAdded==true){
                foodBox.setText("");
                setFood(0.0);
            }
            isClicked=true;
            animal=1;
            addFood();
            valueAdded=true;//value in the box
                }


    });


    catButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (valueAdded){
               foodBox.setText("");}
            isClicked=true;
            animal=2;
            addFood();
            valueAdded=true;
            }

    });
            private void addFood() {
    try{
        aClass aob = new aClass();
        setFood(0.0);
        String a = this.foodBox.getText().toString();
        if(isClicked&&TextUtils.isEmpty(a)){
            if(animal==1){
                a=mob.getDog(); 
            }
            if(animal==2){
                a=mob.getCat();
            }
            this.foodBox.setText(a);
            double d=Double.parseDouble(a);
            setFood(d);
        }else{
            if(TextUtils.isEmpty(a)){
            a="0";
        }
        double d=Double.parseDouble(a);
        setFood(d);
        }
    } 
        catch (Exception e){
        this.showAnswer.setText("Please input animals in numbers");
        addFood();
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Errr...

The only code I use to achieve 1) is:

```
    // Clear text when clicked
    host.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            host.setText("");
        }
    });
```

`host` just being an EditText. Works just fine? I think you are making this more complicated than it is.

Comment: its very strange. could it be something to do with the code in the addFood method?

Comment: I wouldn't use the TextChanged listener, especially not like that. The valueAdded variable you have seems really silly, you should check on something like `foodBox.getText().length()` instead to ensure that there's data inside the EditText field. Rethink your design.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I'm teaching myself so lots of silly stuff going on :/

Comment: No worries, sorry if I was too harsh. :)

Comment: Naa, I'm just pleased to get help :)

Answer (score 3):

To clear When Clear Button is Clicked:

```
firstName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.firstName);

clear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clearsearchSubmit);

clear.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.clearsearchSubmit);
        firstName.setText("");
    }
});
```

It Worked For me. Hope It Helps.

Answer (score 0):

For 1) onClick did not work for me as I had to press twice to call onClickListener. Other approach would be setOnFocusChangeListener()

```
editTextView.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if(hasFocus){
                    editTextView.getText().clear();
                }
            }
        });
```

For 2) solution given by ashim888 works well.